# Is it possible to get EmulationStation as a Snap package?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, snap, emulation

Development of EmulationStation seems to have stopped, and I can't get it to install on Ubuntu 18.04. [There is a LaunchPad PPA](https://launchpad.net/~emulationstation/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), and on the site it has this message:

> EmulationStation upstream is DEAD (there's no maintenance there anymore), build is broken on 17.04, GO AWAY.

So, I have low hopes for getting EmulationStation to install via `apt`. Would it be possible to get EmulationStation in a snap format? Can I package my own snap with Ubuntu 16.04 libraries in it? (or whatever distro works)

What about Flatpak or AppImage?

Comment: You can definitely create a snap with 16.04 libs in it, give it a try.

Comment: Use the [Ubuntu Tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/create-your-first-snap#0) and the [guide for C/C++ snaps](https://docs.snapcraft.io/c-c-applications/7817) in the documentation. Fork [this](https://github.com/snapcrafters/fork-and-rename-me) to make a GitHub repo for your progress and track your progress. Also post [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-wishlist-suggestions-wanted/567) with your request and link to your repo (or state your intent to snap that).